# how to get screen coords using projection with a multipolygon in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am using D3 to display customer location within counties. For MOST of my counties I am not having any problems. I am using the following code snippet to get the XY coordinates for my counties

```
var countyCoords = county.geometry.coordinates[0];
...
for (var j = 0; j < countyCoords.length; j++)
{
    var x = projection(countyCoords[j])[0];
    var y = projection(countyCoords[j])[1];
```

Works like a charm, with one exception. If my county.geometry["type"] is a MultiPolygon, these lines fail. How do I get the screen locations (i.e. x,y) of a MultiPolygon in d3?

Here are some lines from my input to d3.json() [edited for display here]

```
"counties":
 {
"type":"GeometryCollection",
"geometries":[
         {"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"NAME":"Chester"},"id":"Chester","arcs":[[[13,2111,15,2112,17,18,2113,2114,20,2115,2116,-1951,2117,2118,2119,9,2120,11,2121]],[[2122,2123]]]},
         {"type":"Polygon","properties":{"NAME":"Clarion"},"id":"Clarion","arcs":[[-1966,2124,-2004,-2018,-2063]]},
```

I get the counties by using this line:

```
counties = topojson.feature(topoData, topoData.objects.counties);
```

I iterate through the counties and collect the XY locations mentioned above like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < counties.features.length; i++)
{
    var county = counties.features[i];
    var countyCoords = county.geometry.coordinates[0];
    var xy = [];

    for (var j = 0; j < countyCoords.length; j++)
    {
        var x = projection(countyCoords[j])[0];
        var y = projection(countyCoords[j])[1];

        var dataPoint = [x,y];
        xy.push(dataPoint);
    }

    county.properties["XY"] = xy;
}
```

This works correctly for the county "Clarion" but fails for the county "Chester".

Comment: You should be able to just pass `county` to `projection` to get back all the coordinates at once. Also note that usually you don't need to get the coordinates explicitly, see e.g. [this tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/).

Comment: I probably wasn't clear in my question. I am displaying the counties already. I am also displaying my customer locations already. I am implementing a point-in-polygon algorithm and need the XY locations of the counties and the customer locations for that algorithm. Everything is working fine for my implementation of the algorithm except when I need the XY locations of a multipolygon.

Comment: one more piece of information...this line:console.log(projection(county)); produces this output : [NaN, NaN]

Comment: Could you simply get the coordinates by iterating over the elements you have drawn already?

Comment: I thought that I was doing that above. I'm going to edit my original post and supply some additional information that I hope can give you a better idea of what I'm doing.

Comment: My point is that somewhere you're adding DOM elements for those locations (e.g. `circle`s). You can get the screen coordinates from those, can't you? Besides, for point-in-polygon you can use the unprojected coordinates as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GeoJSON multipolygon has an additional array level to its structure that you'd need to iterate through:

http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html

To account for this, you'd have to do something like this:

```
if (county.geometry.type == "MultiPolygon") {
 for (var x=0; x< countyCoords.length;x++) {

  for (var j = 0; j < countyCoords[x].length; j++) {
    var x = projection(countyCoords[x][j])[0];
    var y = projection(countyCoords[x][j])[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to solve my problem. It is pretty much the suggestion of Elijah but tailored to my specific needs. (Note: this is only for Multipolygon types, normal polygon types should use the code identified in my original post). Also, please feel free to point out anywhere where my code can be improved.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < counties.features.length; i++)
{
    var county = counties.features[i];

    if (county.geometry["type"] === "MultiPolygon")
    {
        var xy = [];

        for (var k = 0; k < county.geometry.coordinates.length; k++)
        {
            var countyCoords = county.geometry.coordinates[k][0];

            for (var j = 0; j < countyCoords.length; j++)
            {
                var x = projection(countyCoords[j])[0];
                var y = projection(countyCoords[j])[1];

                var dataPoint = [x,y];
                xy.push(dataPoint);
            }
            county.properties["XY"] = xy;
        }
    }
}
```